# How can I see many grep results page by page?

Tags: grep

I am new to Linux. If I use grep and there are so many results that they cannot all be displayed at once, how can I view the results page by page, so that I get a chance to see them all without missing any?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

try

```
grep YOUR_PATTERN_AND_OPTION YOUR_PATH | less
```

or

```
grep YOUR_PATTERN_AND_OPTION YOUR_PATH | more
```

Comment: love the "more or less" answer!

Comment: And one more doubt. Is there a way I can specify to grep the pattern only in a specified type of file? Like if I want results from .c or .cpp files alone?

Comment: @kiki - Yup, such as `grep YOUR_PATTERN *.c -or *.cpp`

Comment: And the path need not be specified?

Comment: I we are mentioning both `| more` and `| less`, we should also mention `| most`. And if you want the normal `vim` syntax highlighting on the pipe output, you can pipe into `| view -`. And if you want to do it in a script, use `| ${PAGER:-less}`.

Comment: oh boy! You got me all confused. You are talking to a beginner here.

Comment: @kiki - The path is optional, if omit, mean is from the `pwd` onwards. You can supply the path to ensure search is correctly on the path you want.

Comment: hmm, fine...anyways, i got it to work only by specifying --include i.e grep PATTERN --include *.cpp

Comment: Could someone explain ajreal's comment in more details please :
> And if you want to do it in a script, use | ${PAGER:-less} I'm not sure to understand what `PAGER:-less` is doing !

Answer (score -5):

you can use the option `--pager=less`

Comment: Are you sure about this? I cannot seem to find it in the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) page